# What technology does Flow Task Manager use for their Web app client?

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I have just been looking at http://www.getflow.com/ and their UI looks pretty slick, Mac App style.
I was wondering if anyone knows what javascript library did they use for their client?

I couldn't find much in the page source code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no JavaScript expert, but based on a quick look at the [source code](https://app.getflow.com/assets/standard_interface.js), it seems that it's all homegrown. They use jQuery all over the place, and some [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/), but the UI they drew themselves.

Comment: yeah looks like it's mostly homegrown. I was wondering if they used Cappuccino web framework http://cappuccino.org, but can't tell.

Answer (score 2):

One of the developers explained what libraries/frameworks they have been using for the frontend.

http://www.quora.com/Flow-web-application/What-JavaScript-framework-does-Flow-use-for-its-web-frontend

Here's my brief:

Most of the UI stuff is custom (jQuery for DOM manipulation, selection and utility) and hand crafted custom made CSS specifically built for Flow. Other than that the stack uses a slightly modified version of Backbone and its dependency Underscore. And of course, the backend is node and realtime communication is handled by Socket.io